# Unzip a .tgz file in R using Windows

Tags: r

I am new to R.  I have some code that was used to download and unzip a file but it was using a Mac and I have Windows.  I installed the HelpersMG package which allowed me to download the file, but I can't figure out how to unzip.  Here is the code:

`wget("https://mothur.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/wiki/silva.nr_v138.tgz")`  <- This worked

`tar -zxvf silva.nr_v138.tgz` <-This part doesn't work

Could someone provide advice?
Thank you!

Comment: Does the file size appear correct? Sometimes when I download a compressed from AWS, I instead receive a text HTML file containing a redirection link, rather than the actual compressed file.

Comment: Try `unzip` function.